# Load values from Models.py into Views.py

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to create a page that allows a user to change certain CSS variables in the Django admin page and I am having some issues pulling a single value from the `models.py` and assigning it to a variable in my `views.py`. Assigning the colors inside the Django admin page works but I am unsure of how I would go about setting the `linkcolor` variable in `views.py` to the `link_color` variable in `models.py`.

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import cssEditor

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    linkcolor = "#000" # Grab link_color from models.py here
    linkfont = "Brush Script MT" # Grab link_font from models.py here
    linkbc = "whitesmoke" # Grab link_bc from models.py here
    return render(request, "SocialLinks/index.html", {"linkcolor":linkcolor, "linkfont":linkfont, "linkbc":linkbc})
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class cssEditor(models.Model):
    link_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="000000")
    link_font = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="Brush Script MT")
    link_bc = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#F5F5F5")
```

```
admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from SocialLinks.forms import *

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(cssEditor)
class cssEditor(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = cssForm
```

```
forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from SocialLinks.models import *

class cssForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = cssEditor
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "link_color": TextInput(attrs={"type": "color"}),
            "link_bc": TextInput(attrs={"type": "color"}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query the model in the view and get the values.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import cssEditor

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    editor = cssEditor.objects.get(X) # <- X is the instance pk
    return render(
        request,
        "SocialLinks/index.html",
        {
            "linkcolor":editor.linkcolor,
            "linkfont":editor.linkfont,
            "linkbc":editor.linkbc
         }
    )
```

Now, you don't mention how you bind the instances to something, like the user, or if it is a single instance. You have several ways to query the model. In the example I use the pk that I magically get it ;) . That is something you need to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks! So basically I just need a way to pull in the model as an object then reference each part? -Edit. I got it, just had to add `editor = cssEditor.objects.get(pk=1)` didn't realize `pk=1` was the default. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you solve it!